# Rails decimal (currency) number not saving when the scale part changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decimal

I have a price field in Rails created as a decimal with precision 8 and scale 2 (or numeric(8,2) in Postgres). When I try to update the scale part, it generates an empty transaction, but I cannot understand why. Any idea on what is going on?

Console outputs:

```
irb(main):051:0> puts o.price
8.0
=> nil

irb(main):052:0> o.price = "8,22"
=> "8,22"

irb(main):053:0> puts o.price
8.22
=> nil

irb(main):054:0> o.save
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
=> true

irb(main):055:0> o.reload; puts o.price    
8.0
=> nil
```

**EDIT:** Updating the whole number works normally, the problem only appears when updating the scale part:

```
irb(main):017:0* puts o.price
8.0
=> nil

irb(main):018:0> o.price = "9,22"
=> "9,22"

irb(main):019:0> o.save
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.9ms)  UPDATE "order_items" SET "price" = 9.22, "updated_at" = '2014-01-10 20:17:31.753908' WHERE "order_items"."id" = 1469
   (22.1ms)  COMMIT
=> true

irb(main):020:0> o.reload; puts o.price
9.22
=> nil
```

**EDIT 2:** Also tested with others decimals ( 8,22 => 8,44) and it works. The problem occurs when the price is rounded to 0 ( 8,00 => 8,22 doesn't update)

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. It saves as 822.0 with single quotes ('8.22').

Comment: It has nothing to do with single or double quotes, but with separator.

Comment: Isn't that because `o.price.class` is `BigDecimal` and it terminates at unkown values? http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-new

Comment: Yes, it's a BigDecimal, but why does it works when updating the whole number?

Comment: Strange, I don't get any decimal value with `,` separator on RoR 4.0 and Postgres 9.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in the delocalize gem. Upgrading it from 0.3.1 to 0.3.2 solved the problem. Issue:

https://github.com/clemens/delocalize/issues/57

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
o.price = "8,22"
```

You assign string object, not decimal value. Since you are using coma as a separator `'8,22'.to_f` returns `8.0`.

Try assigning a number instead.

```
o.price = 8.22
```

Comment: I tried that, but if I set o.price = "9,22" it saves normally. The problem happens when I edit only the scale part. As you said, '9,22'.to_f returns 9.0, but in this case it works saving 9.22

Comment: Have you override `price=` or `price` method? What your schema says about this column?

Comment: Almost that! It was the delocalize gem that was messing with the conversions.